# Using SQLAlchemy scoped_session with Celery

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, celery

I'm using SQLAlchemy with Celery **NOT** as a backend (the Celery backend I'm using is RabbitMQ).

Reading this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31999269/how-to-setup-sqlalchemy-session-in-celery-tasks-with-no-global-variable) and the SQLAlchemy documentation I come up with this solution:

First I've implemented a class that extends the Celery' `Task` class:

```python
class DBTask(Task):
    _engine = None
    _Session = None

    def __init__(self):
        self.logger = get_task_logger('__name__')

    def after_return(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.logger.info("DBTask: Removing session. {}".format(self._Session))
        if self._Session is not None:
            self.logger.debug("DBTask: Session removed. {}".format(self._Session))
            self._Session.remove()

    @property
    def engine(self):
        if self._engine is None:
            self.logger.info("DBTask: Creating engine.")
            self.config = GlobalConfigReader().get_config()
            self._engine = create_engine(self.config['postgres_uri'], pool_pre_ping=True)
        return self._engine

    @property
    def Session(self):
        if self._Session is None:
            self._Session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=self.engine))
            self.logger.info("DBTask: Creating new session: {}".format(self._Session))
            Base.metadata.create_all(self.engine)
        return self._Session
```

And in one of my task I do the following:

```python
self process(self, message):
        try:
            session = self.Session()

            db_alert = self._find_existing_alert(session, message['event'], 
            session.commit()
        except:
            self.logger.debug("Rolling back session. {}".format(session))
            session.rollback()
            raise
        # further processing
        context.delay(message)
```

It seems that every Celery Task running in a thread creates a new DB connection and never close it. This is a prometheus graph of database status:

[image: prometheus graph]

It also looks like the connections greatly increase at the start of celery and they remain somewhat stable. (The drop is because I've restarted Postgres).

Another thing I cannot explain is why, when `after_return` is called,`self_Session` is always None so `self._Session.remove()` is never called.

[EDIT]:
Looking through all the logs I've realized that sometimes `self._Session.remove()` is not None so the `self._Session.remove()` is called but not every time `after_return`.